# Cannot convert .csv to .arff file

Tags: java, class, csv, weka, arff

I run the following command:
java weka.core.converters.CSVLoader filename.csv > filename.arff

but i have an error telling me:
Could not find or load main class weka.core.converters.CSVLoder.

What is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not find or load main class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647448/could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

Comment: Where are you executing this command? Do you have the compiled weka classes unpacked in directories? Or do you have a weka.jar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in my opinion that weka.jar is not in your classpath.

You can either add weka.jar to your classpath, or run the same command but adding the classpath for weka:

```
java -cp "%CLASSPATH;C:\progs\Weka-3-6\weka.jar" weka.core.converters.CSVLoader filename.csv > filename.arff
```