# Could not find or load main class: what steps are next for debugging?

Tags: java

I know there are many posts on this. I have tried the advice on those threads.

- [Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647448/could-not-find-or-load-main-class)
- [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

I compile a class like this... (it creates a NER_Sample.class file)

```
javac -cp "jar1:jar2:nlp:" NER_Sample.java
```

Then I try to run it like this

```
java -cp "jar1:jar2:nlp:" NER_Sample englishPCFG.ser.gz parser/data/testsent.txt
```

I get `Could not find or load main class NER_Sample`

NER_Sample has the declaration `package nlp;`

But this gives the same error

```
java -cp "jar1:jar2:nlp:" nlp.NER_Sample englishPCFG.ser.gz parser/data/testsent.txt
```

What do I try next?

Comment: Rather than just "trying the advice", you should read and try to understand what the answers actually say.  In particular, http://stackoverflow.com/a/18093929/139985 explains in great detail what the causes of this exception are.  But you do need to read it ... AND the pages it links to ... because this is not a problem you can solve by "trying advice".  You have to UNDERSTAND what you are doing.

Comment: @StephenC that's fair. But in this case, the issue was that the package had to be in a directory that mirrored the package declaration. Which was just something I did not know! (And just learned from SO...)

Answer (score 4):

**Use `-Xdiag`**

It can happen the message `Could not find or load main class NER_Sample` really means the class is found but can not be loaded, since there are other referenced classes that are not found on classpath.

`java -Xdiag` will tell you more, such as what classes are missing next.

Comment: Man, you ended a very big headache I was getting. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Add the current directory to the runtime classpath

```
java -cp .:jar1:jar2 nlp.NER_Sample englishPCFG.ser.gz parser/data/testsent.txt
```

Comment: Does the class `NER_Sample` have a package declaration?

Comment: the declaration = package nlp;

Comment: Java expects `NER_Sample.class` itself to be in the `nlp` folder. Move the file to that location and use `java -cp .:jar1:jar2 nlp.NER_Sample ...`. Better to move the source file there & compile again

Comment: This is all in directory ~/nlp/nlp    where should I move the code?

Comment: Move the source & class to the nlp directory _relative_ to where youre attempting to compile & run the class