# Can't figure out how to run my jar file "could not find or load main class"

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a jar file and run it using `java -cp main.jar com.test.Foo.Main` but I keep getting:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.test.Foo.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.Foo.Main
```

This is my file structure. So I'm thinking the line in my `Main.java` should be `package com.test.Foo` correct?

[image]

I'm compiling my `Main.java` with `javac Main.java` which outputs a `Main.class` file. Afterward, I create a jar file using `jar cfm main.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF Main.class` and finally while I'm in the same directory as the jar file `<root>/src/com/test/Foo/` I run `java -cp main.jar com.test.Foo.Main` and that's when I run into the above error. Any idea how I can run this file like this (and yes I need it to run with this command specifically)?

**Main.java**

```
package com.test.Foo;

public class Main {
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    System.out.println("I am com.test.Foo.Main");
  }
}
```

**META-INF/MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.test.Foo.Main
```

I tried using some of the options given in [this popular SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647448/could-not-find-or-load-main-class) and nothing helped.

Comment: "Main" is probably a bad name for a class ... but it sounds like your problem is that you forgot "Foo":  CHANGE MANIFEST.MF: `Main-Class: com.test.Foo.Main`.  I'd also suggest: `java -jar main.jar`.

Comment: Sorry I had just added that into the error. I still get the same problem even if I include `Foo` -- `java -cp main.jar com.test.Foo`

Comment: Well I'm not sure what a `pom` file is so I'm going to say no. Should this be my next step?

Comment: how do you create your jar file ? what's your IDE ?

Comment: @Mehdi so I create the jar file using `jar cfm main.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF Main.class` and for this test project I'm just using VSCode. Typically, I would use IntelliJ.

Comment: @BrandonBenefield ok wait I'm writing your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The picture you're showing in your question **is your project structure not your jar structure**.*

> When you create a jar file, the structure for that jar file might be
>   different with your source code folder structure.

Every IDE (such as eclipse, netbeans, IntelliJ) has a mechanism for creating JAR files. In your case when you open the created jar file (using zip apps like winrar) you should see something like this :

```
com
  |
  test
     |
     Foo
       |
       Main
META-INF
       |
       MANIFEST.MF
```

*This should be the ordering of your files and folders, otherwise **Java** can not find your main class from **MANIFEST.MF***

Now to solve this problem:

> 1. Open your jar file using a zip application like winrar
> 2. check the folder structure residing inside your jar file as I draw
> 3. Fix it right away within the winrar or try to correct your project structure to produce the structure I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The class is called `com.test.Foo.Main` you need to specify the full name in the command:

```
java -cp main.jar com.test.Foo.Main
```

or you can use the simpler

```
java -jar main.jar
```

Comment: So running the `java -jar main.jar` returns `no main manifest attribute, in main.jar`. Ideas on why this is happening if I'm including the manifest file when jarring everything?

Answer (score 0):

Check your META-INF/MANIFEST.MF for the attribute of `Manifest-Version: 1.0`

This attribute must be there.

---

Edit:

You need to move to the source root `src/` and issue below command to create a valid jar.

`javac com/test/Foo/*.java`

and, create the jar using,

`jar cmf com/test/Foo/MANIFEST.MF main.jar com/test/Foo/*.class`

The thing is, package structure should match with the folder structure apparently.

Comment: Not working either, I tried adding it to the top and bottom of the file and it's still not working.

Comment: @BrandonBenefield Edited answer to generate the jar in correct way.